# Animating multiple bar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two bar graphs `oli` and `prachanda`. I want to increase height of these to graph in real-time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg'

x1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

labels = ['2018/04', '2018/05', '2018/06', '2018/07', '2018/08', '2018/09']

n_groups = 6
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.20
opacity = 0.8

fig.canvas.set_window_title('Nagarik News')

oli = plt.bar(index, x1, bar_width,
              alpha=opacity,
              label='Oli')

prachanda = plt.bar(index + bar_width, x1, bar_width,
                    alpha=opacity,
                    label='Prachanda')

deuwa = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width, x1, bar_width,
                alpha=opacity,
                label='Deuwa')


def init_oli():
    ax.set_ylim(0, 50)
    return oli


def update_oli(frame):
    new_height = oli[0].get_height() + frame
    oli[0].set_height(new_height)
    return oli


def init_prachanda():
    return prachanda


def update_prachanda(frame):
    new_height = prachanda[0].get_height() + frame
    prachanda[0].set_height(new_height)
    return prachanda


frames = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_oli, frames=frames, init_func=init_oli, blit=True, interval=500, repeat=False)
ani2 = FuncAnimation(fig, update_prachanda, frames=frames, init_func=init_prachanda, blit=True, interval=500,
                     repeat=False)

plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Count by Politician')

plt.xticks(index + bar_width, labels)
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


# writer = FFMpegWriter()
# ani.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=writer)
```

The problem is only the height of the graph `prachanda` is increasing.

Comment: You need one FuncAnimation, not two.

Comment: Is it possible to return two artist object from a single animation function. I tried it but got this error AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

Comment: The return type of the animating function needs to be a list of artists anyways, so you will just need to return all the bars at once.

Comment: def init():
   return oli, prachanda


def update(frame):
    return oli, prachanda

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames, init_func=init, blit=True, interval=500, repeat=False)

But I am gettingAttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

Comment: A list of artists, not a tuple of barcontainers.

Comment: Okay, it works. Is there any cleaner way of doing this without creating a separate list and appending all artist object into it.

Comment: What's not clean about creating a list of artists?